# Optimalization of join in postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Hi Im looking for optimalization of my query in postgresql. I have query that joins another table, based on condition within same row, but Im not so sure, that it will avoid of checking other condition in another table.

Example query:

```sql
select e2.*
from entity e1
left join another_entity e2 on e1.name = 'Json' and e1.second_name = e2.second_name
```

So as you can see Im checking the first condition in `on` within same record scope, and then the 2nd condition based on another record in another table. Do you know how it gonna work? Does first condition avoid of checking others using another table in postgresql?

Comment: Try with a simple optimization by adding an index on `second_name` from the second table.  This should speed up the join.

Comment: Already have that. I just want to uderstand that checking the first condition will exclude checking anything from another table

Comment: You would need to check the execution plan.  An index on `name` in the first table might help along the lines of what you have in mind.

Comment: Re "Does first condition avoid of checking others using another table in postgresql?" - it depends on data (distribution) and Postgres server query optimisation strategy. If most your records have name = 'Json', then server may join first and filter after.

Comment: Since it is a left outer join, it doesn't matter if you put a condition on the left table in the join condition or in the `WHERE` condition.

Answer (score 2):

To better understand how your query works you should write it like this:

```
select e2.*
from   entity e1
       left OUTER join another_entity AS e2 
          on e1.second_name = e2.second_name
WHERE  e1.name = 'Json'
```

The member "e1.name = 'Json'" has nothing to do in the join operator.

Then, depending on cardinalities, the first operation in the query execution plan, would be a restriction (WHERE) and the JOIN will be executed.

So the candidate index could be:

```
CREATE INDEX X001 ON entity (name, second_name);
```

If the cardinalities drive to an execution plan with the join in first operation, then the candidate index will be:

```
CREATE INDEX X002 ON entity (second_name, name);
```